# A mystery IndexOutOfRange Exception recurring when reading from a full EventLog

Tags: c#, event-log

I'm maintaining an application which uses the Windows Application Event Log to 'scan' for errors from another application.

I need to find the first entry occurring since a specified time. So, what I've done so far is looped back from the latest Event Log entry (`Entries.Count-1`), until an entry is found *before* the specified time. The next entry must be the first one since this specified time, so I then loop forwards from this entry until the last one (`Entries.Count-1`).

However. I keep getting `IndexOutOfRange Exceptions` which I am finding difficult to resolve or understand.

Also, I have realised that some of my assumptions about the Event Log are very likely to be faulty - and I am struggling to find relevant documentation to correct myself.

The `IndexOutOfRange Exception` only occurs when the EventLog is full. Also, the [log retention policy setting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721981.aspx) is set to 'Overwrite events as needed.'

---

**Code**

```
// This method is called every time a log is written to the Application Event Log
private void parseApplicationLogEntries()
{ 
    // Assumes the first log since the specified time is the most recent one
    int firstLog = log.Entries.Count-1;

    // Loops through the logs from the last one until the first,
    // stopping if it finds one before the specified time. 
    // The next entry must be the first one since the specified
    // time, so set the firstLog to its index and then break. 
    for (int entry = log.Entries.Count - 1; entry > 0; entry--)
    {
        DateTime logEntryTimeWritten = log.Entries[entry].TimeWritten;

        if (logEntryTimeWritten < specifiedTime)
        {
             firstLog = entry + 1;
             break;
        }
    }

    //
    for (int entry = firstLog; entry <= log.Entries.Count - 1; entry++)
    {
        string logSource = log.Entries[entry].Source; 

        if (logSource == sourceIAmLookingFor)
        {
            // Do some stuff
            // It's found, so break
        }
    }
}
```

So. There are plenty of doubtful assumptions here, and no Exception handling where there should obviously be some.

1. This makes the assumption that the Event Log indexes are ordered from oldest to newest entry, by time. (e.g. `Entries[0]` is the oldest entry, and `Entries[Entries.Count-1]` is the newest entry)
2. There is no Exception Handling to catch the IndexOutOfRange Exception.

---

**Work towards a solution so far**

- Researched the [EventLog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Diagnostics.EventLog(v=vs.110).aspx) on MSDN and elsewhere.
- Written a program to flood the Event Log with entries in an attempt to replicate the conditions under which the Exception is occurring. (I cannot get the issue to recur under a development environment, even though it recurs frequently in a live environment.)

---

I am honestly at a complete loss. I can think of some 'half-fixes' (e.g. make the Event Log's maximum size huge, and stick in an Exception handler which just does nothing) - but what I really want is to understand why this is happening and fix it *properly*. Since the index should always be between `0` and `Entries.Count-1` I don't have a clue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Apologies I've probably missed some of the things I've tried. This has been a problem which has recurred now and then for some months now - I've done bits and pieces over a few months, for days worth of my time.

Comment: if `log.Entries.Count == 0` then `firstLog == -1` and the second loop is entered with `entry == -1`

Comment: Thank you. That's a good find. This error always occurs with a full log though, so the cause of it must be something else.

Comment: The cause may very well be something else. On the other hand if you tell event log to 'Overwrite events as needed.', in a certain sense a full log is the same as an empty log.

Comment: How do you mean? I've not been able to find documentation on what exactly *happens* when it overwrites events as needed. Particularly related to the index / order of entries.

Comment: If writing has to wrap around in some way and your code has a first entry with index of `-1` then wrapping around might lead to an `IndexOutOfRangeException`. I am not saying that is what is happening, but eliminating the path that leads to an `IndexOutOfRangeException` and testing again seems like a good idea.

Comment: Would be more helpful if you could identify the *exact line* that is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to access the `EventLog` in this way to review the newest entries.

Instead of calling a method to iterate through the `EventLog` each time a new `Entry` is written, it is simpler (and safer) to access the `Entry` more directly using the event handler which triggers each time an `Entry` is written.

```
private void eventLog_Application_EntryWritten(object sender, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
{
    // Process e.Entry    
}
```